# How to display icon from OpenWeatherMap API using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

I'm trying to develop an android weather application for an assignment I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrVY2la7lCI) on youtube to create it everything works fine but I couldn't display the icon from the "weather" object on the below JSON. I can get the data as String and display it but I don't know how to display icon using the link.
[Sample link to weather icon from OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png)

**API JSON FORMAT**

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 350
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1560350645,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5122,
    "message": 0.0139,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1560343627,
    "sunset": 1560396563
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
  "id": 420006353,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
  }
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
    package com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {


    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

   public static  Retrofit getClient(){ //creating object

        if (retrofit == null){

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() //Retrofit.Builder class uses the Builder API to allow defining the URL end point for the HTTP operations and finally build a new Retrofit instance.
                    //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=76a35a17f3e1bce771a09f3555b614a8
                    .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        }


        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
    package com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiInterface {


    @GET("weather?APPID=76a35a17f3e1bce771a09f3555b614a8&units=metric")//http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=76a35a17f3e1bce771a09f3555b614a8
    Call<Example> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String name);


}
```

**Weather.java**

```
    package com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Weather {

        @SerializedName("main")
        String main;

        @SerializedName("description")
        String description;

        @SerializedName("icon")
        String icon;


        public String getMain() { return main; }
        public void setMain(String main) { this.main = main; }

        public String getDescription() { return description; }
        public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }

        public String getIcon() { return icon; }
        public void setIcon(String icon) { this.icon = icon; }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.dhanurjan.weather;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit.ApiClient;
import com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit.ApiInterface;
import com.dhanurjan.weather.Retrofit.Example;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button searchBtn;
    TextView tempText , feelText , humidityText, lon, lat, country, sunrise, sunset, descText, windSpeed;
    EditText cityName;
    ImageView icon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchBtn = findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        tempText = findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        feelText = findViewById(R.id.feelText);
        humidityText = findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        country = findViewById(R.id.country);
        sunrise = findViewById(R.id.sunrise);
        sunset = findViewById(R.id.sunset);
        lon = findViewById(R.id.lonText);
        lat = findViewById(R.id.latText);
        cityName = findViewById(R.id.cityName);
        descText = findViewById(R.id.descText);
        icon = findViewById(R.id.icon);
        windSpeed = findViewById(R.id.windSpeed);


        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                getWeatherData(cityName.getText().toString().trim());

            }
        });
    }

    private void getWeatherData(String name){

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                tempText.setText(response.body().getMain().getTemp()+" ℃");
                feelText.setText("Feels Like :"+" "+response.body().getMain().getFeels_like()+" ℃");
                lon.setText("Longitude :"+" "+response.body().getCoord().getLon()+" °E");
                lat.setText("Latitude :"+" "+response.body().getCoord().getLat()+" °N");
                humidityText.setText("Humidity :"+" "+response.body().getMain().getHumidity()+" %");
                country.setText(response.body().getSys().getCountry());
                sunrise.setText("Sunrise :"+" "+response.body().getSys().getSunrise()+" AM");
                sunset.setText("Sunset :"+" "+response.body().getSys().getSunset()+" PM");
                windSpeed.setText("windSpeed :"+" "+response.body().getWind().getSpeed()+" KM/H");
                descText.setText(response.body().getWeatherList().get(0).getDescription());
                //icon.setImageIcon(response.body().getWeatherList().get(0).getIcon());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```